# Add string with backslash in file using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed, vagrant, vagrantfile

I need to add a text string:

```
--with-mpm=event \
```

to `httpd.spec` on 138th position.

I tried:

```
sed -i '138i--with-mpm=event \\' /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/httpd.spec
```

This code runs in bash script of `Vagrantfile` during bootstrapping virtual machine. However, the script returns error.

When I check `httpd.spec`, output is a string missing backslash:

```
--with-mpm=event
```

It works okay running it directly in shell of virtual machine though.

How can I fix it with `sed`?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually, try adding up backslashes until you get them. ``\\\``? ``\\\\``?

Comment: Thanks,  i added plus two backslashes in code and it fixed issue. It helps. I can note your answer like right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule of thumb when dealing with backslashes is keep adding up backslashes until you get the expected result.

In this case, a literal backslash here needs to be coded with four backslashes:

```
sed -i '138i--with-mpm=event \\\\' /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/httpd.spec
```